# Height of div adjusting to resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering if it is possible to make div adjust to height of screen view. What I want to achieve, is to make the first div always adapt to resolution and push everything beneath off screen. That greyish part should be off screen for any resolution. I know height is a bit tricky, but is this possible ?

[image]

Comment: you can use : `div {height:100vh;}`  see https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you !

Comment: Also, it leaves me with a question. I managed to set height to 86vh, it fits my needs the best. If I got it right, then it means only 86% of view port, but it takes the whole view port for me. Is there something I missed ?

Comment: Possible that you have paddings or margins (or collapsing-margin effects) . Without html and CSS that reproduce you issue. We can only try guesses. TJis might be a new question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS Has Viewport and viewheight units(namely `vw` and `vh`)

Add This in your CSS:

```
div {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use : `div {height:100vh;}`

see https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

> **vw unit**
>
> Equal to 1% of the width of the initial containing block.
>
> In the example below, if the width of the viewport is 200mm, the font size of h1 elements will be 16mm (i.e. (8×200mm)/100).
>
> ```
>    `h1 { font-size: 8vw }`
> ```
>
> **vh unit**
>
> ```
>    Equal to 1% of the height of the initial containing block.
> ```
>
> **vmin unit**
>
> ```
>     Equal to the smaller of vw or vh.
> ```
>
> **vmax unit**
>
> ```
>     Equal to the larger of vw or vh.
> ```

See also http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units for browsers support

Answer (score 1):

CSS has viewport units. Try this:

`height: 100vh`

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length)

**Explanation**:
Viewport units are based on percentages of viewport.

1vh: 1/100th of the height of the viewport.

1vw: 1/100th of the width of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
div { width: 100%; height: 100%; min-width: 1000px; min-height: 1000px; }
```

That way div can't be smaller then 1000px, but its not good for mobile browsers.